# Spring 3.2, Jackson2 ObjectMapper configuration

Tags: json, spring, serialization, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a problem that can not be resolved on the configuration of ObjectMapper. I need to configure it to ignore those parameters that do not have my POJO...so easy but I configured a thousand different ways and I can not make it work.

my servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" >
     <property name="objectMapper">
     <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
         <property name="featuresToDisable">
           <array>
            <util:constant 
            static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES"/>
          </array>
         </property>
      </bean>                  
    </property>  
</bean>
```

I have also tried to extend the class ObjectMapper but I get the same results. I see the mapper is configured correctly but i hope MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter receives a different instance of ObjectMapper. I Dont know what else to do to make me ignore the parameters globally.

When I make a request with a parameter that should be ignored (not present on the POJO) gives a syntax error in the request.

Im using:
Spring 3.2.0 
jackson 2.1.2

Best regards and thank´s

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<!-- 
     Implement a custom ObjectMapper and initialize the features you needed 
     eg. FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES 
-->
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.sample.CustomObjectMapper"/>

<!-- Replace Spring's default message converter -->
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters>
    <ref bean="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution tested on Spring 3.2.18.RELEASE and Jackson 2.7.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper"
    class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value
                type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature">FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES</value>
            <value>false</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```